# quickLookup UnofficialSF not working on Experience - No Records Returned after Salesforce Spring '24 Release

Tags: visual-workflow

quickLookup UnofficialSF package is no longer working in our Prod/Staging org after the Spring '24 release.
Checked the User profile permissions and it has access to object, fields and to run the flow. It was all working previously to the latest SF release. Returns a "No Records Found" result even though it has access to that object. Has anyone else encountered this issue? This package is utilized in a Flow
Please help!

Comment: This package is utilized in a Flow

Comment: You will have to check with UnofficialSF support:  https://unofficialsf.com/feedback-and-comments/